# Android on back key pressed stop recorder

Tags: android, back, onkeydown

I have a recorder created in the `onCreate()`, like final `MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder();`, and i need to stop recording when the user press the back button.

In order to stop the recorder i used the following code.

```
final MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.noise);
    // elementi
        TextView picco=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.picco_recorder);
        ImageView noise_bar=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.noise_bar);
        ImageView noise_bar_red=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.noise_bar_red);
        ImageView imgnoise = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_noise);
        imgnoise.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
                Intent torna_home=new Intent(Noise.this,Index.class);
                startActivity(torna_home);
            }
        });
    // noise
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
        try{
            recorder.prepare();
        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
            Log.d("Errore",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.d("Errore",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();
        double db=10*Math.log(recorder.getMaxAmplitude());
        picco.setText("" + (int)db);
        noise_bar.scrollTo(0, (int)((int)db*1.5));
        noise_bar_red.scrollTo(0, (int)((int)db*1.5));
        Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RecorderTask(recorder), 0, 500);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Intent torna_home=new Intent(Noise.this,Index.class);
        startActivity(torna_home);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
}
private class RecorderTask extends TimerTask{
    TextView risultato=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.picco_recorder);
    TextView max=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.max_recorder);
    TextView media=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.media_recorder);
    ImageView noise_bar=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.noise_bar);
    ImageView noise_bar_red=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.noise_bar_red);
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    public RecorderTask(MediaRecorder recorder){
        this.recorder = recorder;
    }
    public void run(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double db=10*Math.log(recorder.getMaxAmplitude());
                risultato.setText("" + (int)db);
                if(Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString())<(int)db){
                    max.setText("" + (int)db);
                    noise_bar_red.scrollTo(0, (int)((int)db*1.5));
                }
                media.setText(""+((int)db+Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString()))/2);
                noise_bar.scrollTo(0, (int)((int)db*1.5));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

to intercept the back button, but it's outside the onCreate and i can't intercept the recorder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of `onKeyDown`, if the button is back, is to call `onBackPressed`. But since you have overridden the `onKeyDown` it might be that you only call `onKeyDown`. I don't know how it works when you have overridden both functions, but try to remove `onKeyDown` and only keep `onBackPressed` and see if the `recorder.stop()` gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You can override onBackPressed instead:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       //Stop recorder
    }
```

Comment: if i put it in the onCreate it produce an error, if i put it outside, it don't recognise the recorder variable

Comment: @Zak Make it a global variable so you can access it here. This method should be outside the `onCreate`

Comment: keep your recorder variable global. This method will be outside onCreate() only. You will have to declare variable before onCreate() method

Comment: thanks it works. but it doesn't stop the recorder (the imageview created by me stop it, so the code to stop is correct, but doesn't work here)

Comment: i am posting it in the main post, wait a moment

Comment: Ok. Try removing super.onBackPressed(); from method. Or add it as a last line of method

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
//Add your desired code here
}
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override any Key press.
For overriding back button especially use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
   recorder.stop();//or whatever code you use to stop recorder
}
```

also for accessing recorder outside oncreate, declare `MediaRecorder recorder` as global variable, initialize it in `onCreate()` method

Comment: initialize the variable inside onCreate Method. Check that